# Show code line number of Reporting Service Log

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying add custom HttpModule `MyHttpModuler` to Reporting service. But when i deployed my custom HttpModule to SSRS located in remote machine. then browser some report in the report manage site. I got some error in my page . I used to check the log file under the SSRS log folder to find out what happened. and I always find some exception info logged in it. But the exception log don't show the code line number .
The example of log could be like below.

```
library!ReportServer_0-1!728!08/22/2012-13:36:29:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at HandlerLib.MyHttpModuler.TryAuthenticate(HttpApplication context)
   at HandlerLib.MyHttpModuler.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Is there any way to show the code line of exception log so that I can know more detail of my codes flaw?  thanks

Comment: The version of SSRS is 2008 R2. thanks.

Comment: Try copying HandlerLib PDB file with HandlerLib dll.

Comment: Wow...That is good point. PDB File include the debug information? right? It is worth to try.

Comment: Hi, Not Work,  I have add my custom log in SSRS.